# Data aggregation (grouping) in Apache Cassandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I am looking for an elegant solution for data aggregation in Cassandra database. (Problem is as simple as running a group by query in Cassandra)

In our application, we are storing the customer login history in a cassandra table (for obvious benefits of faster write speeds and high TPS support) and currently we are supposed to develop an analytical dashboard on top this data. For this requirement, data aggregation is necessary, which is not available directly in Cassandra.

We have evaluated the option of using Apache Solr on top of Cassandra. Two approaches: Using Solandra or using DataStax. Solandra project is no longer in development and cannot be used for production environments. Datastax EE is not for free (will take up only as a last option).

Please let us know if there are any easier and elegant solutions for our problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you are a small company you may qualify to use DSE for free. datastax.com/startup

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache Spark, along with the DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector. If you run Spark workers on cassandra nodes, you even get locality awareness. Spark is pretty much becoming the defacto for Cassandra analytics.

Comment: Thanks Ashic for your quick response. Can you further provide few pointers/links of how to go about the integration of Cassandra and Spark. Also pls let me now if Datastax spark is free to use or in involves any subscription.

Comment: Apache Spark is an Apache project :) The DataStax Spark connector is free and open source. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: That is cool!! So I can run data aggregation (group by) queries by integrating spark with Cassandra, which is otherwise not possible. Thanks again.

Comment: Yup...and with locality, you can query by only secondary index (i.e. without hitting a parition) without queries turning cluster wide. Which will allow you to do aggregations quicker (i.e. not map reducing across all data).